# config routeProvidar on angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's wrong in my code?

```
     var eeee='1';
 if(eeee==='1'){
             otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/start'
  });
 }
 else{
                 otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/mainpage'
  });
 }
```

I try to make a condition...but I can't do it.

Please help

Comment: this code is so bad that i can only suggest you to read angular docs or tutorials like this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling otherwise without  $routeProvider.It is not acceptable and the code you wrote is not appropiate it should be like:-

Put this code in controller:-

```
 var eeee='1';
     if(eeee==='1'){
           $location.path('/start');
     }
     else{
         $location.path('/mainpage');     
     }
```

PS:- $location.path(); required ng-view in HTML.

Please refer [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

And don't do it in app.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the routes declaration depending on a javascript variable then this should work :

```
var eeee = '1';
if (eeee === '1') {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/start'
    });
}
else {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/mainpage'
    });
}
```

But doesn't look like a good practice